# Run-time Error '438' when button from ActiveX Controls is added

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Excel. I am trying to copy certain information from email body (Outlook) into Excel. My code works fine when I run it from Visual Basic winfow under Excel. I want to lunch the code via button inserted from ActiveX controls. Unfortunately, when I hit the button, it reports

> Run-time Error '438'

at the line `sub1 = InStr([1], myitem.Subject, "ARM_")` Could anyone please help me to solve it? I tried to search for similar issues but I have not managed to find any that would be helpful. Thank you. Please find my code below. I am sorry for inapropriate formating.

```
Sub out()

Dim myOlApp As Object
Dim mynamespace As Object
Dim myitem As Object
Dim myfolder As Object
Dim date1 As Date
Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sub1 As Variant
Dim sub2 As Variant
Dim sub3 As Variant
Dim u As Integer
Dim x As String



k = 1


 date1 = InputBox("zadej datum - dd/mm/yyyy") 'vyskoci box pro zadani datumu

 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'nastavi outlook pro editaci

 Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi") 'otevre adresar outlooku
 Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 'pristup do adresare emailu (inbox)

 i = myfolder.items.Count ' pocet mailu v adresari - vsechny prichozi maily v outlooku

 For i = i - 40 To myfolder.items.Count ' tento cyklus projizdi poslednich 300 mailu ve schrance

    Set myitem = myfolder.items(i) 'editace mailu ve schrance
    sub1 = InStr([1], myitem.Subject, "ARM_") 'vyhleda vsechny maily(nazev), ktere zacinaji "ARM_"
    sub2 = InStr([1], myitem.Body, "Target release to customer:") 'vyhleda text v tele emailu
    sub3 = InStr([1], myitem.Body, "Location")

    'MsgBox InStr([1], myitem.body, "Locations:")
    'Cells(1, 3) = i
     'Cells(2, 3) = myitem.Subject
     'Cells(3, 3) = myitem.ReceivedTime
     'Cells(4, 3) = sub2
     'Cells(5, 3) = sub3


   If myitem.ReceivedTime > date1 And sub1 = 1 Then ' podminky museji byt splneny - datum,text v nazvu mailu,text v mailu

      If sub2 > 0 Then

        k = k + 1
        x = Mid(myitem.Body, sub2 + 27, sub3 - (sub2 + 27)) ' vyhleda ozadovany text
        Cells(k, 1) = myitem.ReceivedTime ' cas doruceni mailu
        Cells(k, 2) = myitem.Subject ' nazev mailu
        'Cells(k, 3) = myitem.Body
        Cells(k, 4) = x
      End If
    End If


 Next i
  'msgtext = myitem.Body
  'Cells(1, 1) = msgtext
  'Cells(1, 2) = myitem.Subject
  'Cells(1, 3) = myitem.ReceivedTime   



End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using square brackets around your integer? `[1]` - try using just `1`

Comment: Hi, I got rid of them and it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Integers do not require square braces around them. Instead of using `[1]` use just `1`